# Probability function

Tags: php, function, random

How can I create a function of probability, choosing between two strings
with a probability range between 1/3, 1/2, 1/1, 2/1, 3/1

My value comes from a slider in a range between -2 and 2

this is my code:

```
$out = array('str1','str2');
$out = $out[array_rand($out)];
```

I want something like this:

```
$val = 0; //-2=1/3, -1=1/2, 0=1/1, 1=2/1, 2=3/1 

function random_str($val){
  ...
  retunt $myRandomValue; //str1 or str2
}
```

[EDITED]

ok, here's how far I could get.
this function does exactly what I want.
But my question from the beginning is: 
**how to simplify this function?**

```
function random_str($val){
   if($var == '-2') { $out = array('str1','str2','str2','str2'); }else
   if($var == '-1') { $out = array('str1','str2','str2'); }else
   if($var ==  '0') { $out = array('str1','str2',); }else
   if($var ==  '1') { $out = array('str1','str1','str2'); }else
   if($var ==  '2') { $out = array('str1','str1','str1','str2'); }
   retun $out[array_rand($out)];
}
```

Comment: The range of an event's probablity is [0,1].  Are you talking about odds, like 1-3 vs 3-1 against, etc?

Comment: Could you elaborate what 2/1 and 3/1 would do ?

Comment: Read about the php rand() function...

Comment: You create a pseudo random number between 0 and 1. Then you decide by comparing that random number to a threshold. That threshold is chosen such that it devides the interval between 0 and 1 into how you would like to have the probabilities...

Comment: This topic can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806006/php-percentage-chance

Comment: yes @C8H10N4O2, it is just that!

Comment: `$var` range may vary between -2 and 2 being equivalent to provability from 1-3 to 3-1.
Ie: -2 = 1-3, -1 = 1-2, 0 = 1-1, 2-1 = 1 and 3-1 = 2

Comment: I edited the question, I think now more clearly my intention;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, here I could only mess depart to mine own reputation but anyway I got a good help in [stackoverflow Portugal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71771/simplificar-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-probabilidades-com-prioridade)

Here is a good solution:

```
function random_str($val){
    // padrão
    $out = array('str1', 'str2');

    while ($var != 0) {

        // menor que zero
        if ($var < 0) {
            array_push($out, 'str2');
            $var++;
        } else { // maior que zero
            array_push($out, 'str1');
            $var--;
        }
    }
    return $out[array_rand($out)];
}
```